# iOS Raw Video Capture - Where to start?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, video-capture

It's easy enough to use the system-supplied user interfaces for taking pictures and movies on supported iOS devices. How do I do *raw* video capture and manipulation in iOS 3 and iOS 4? I'm looking for the names of the relevant classes and methods, and possibly a tutorial or reference from Apple...

Answer (score 1):

You can look at these place

[AVCam sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/)

[How to Play, Record, and Edit Videos in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

[Audio & Video Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/index.html)

[AVCaptureSession preference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Wrapper library by Andrew](http://maniacdev.com/2012/07/easy-to-use-open-source-library-for-ios-video-recording-with-avfoundation)

Answer (score 0):

There good start from Apple with a lots of links that can help. See  [Audio & Video Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_AudioVideo_iPhone/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for tuts, there are a lot [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Coding%20How-Tos#section=Topics&topic=Audio%20%26amp%3B%20Video).

Comment: Look at the AV Foundation stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do raw video capture on iOS anymore (there used to be hack for iOS3, but now that's it's official in iOS4, they disallowed the hack).

And on iOS 4 - I believe this is the best start:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html

(Read a little, then browse to **Processing Frames of Video**)

Cheers,

Oded.